# How to pass multiple parameter to Cucumber Runner file from jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I am executing my test cases from Jenkins and passing multiple cucumber tags from Jenkins to execute my scenario -

Runner File -

```
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/test-report" },
features    = { "src/main/resources/abc/features" },
tags        = {"@Demo","@Alpha"}
)
```

Jenkins Parameter-

```
test -Dcucumber.options="src/main/resources/myuhc2/features/ --tags @Demo, --tags @Alpha"
```

but this is not working and I am getting error -

Tests in error:

Not a file or directory - /home/jenkins/workspace/XYZ2.0/consumer_proj/Alpha

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

Comment: Are you able to execute the same command from a command line?

Comment: Yes I can execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the comma following @Demo.  If you want to AND the tags use:

```
--tags @Demo --tags @Alpha
```

To OR the tags use (no space after comma):

```
--tags @Demo,@Alpha
```