# How do I do Maven to run tests using the features ordering?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests

I'm using the suite `Maven + Selenium + Jenkins` to run integration tests with a e-commerce application.

It happens that [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) doesn't follow the *.feature* files order:

```
1-test_case.feature 
2-test_case.feature 
3-test_case.feature
```

The order that Maven follows is:

```
RunOneTest.class / 2.test_case.feature
RunTwoTest.class / 3.test_case.feature
RunThreeTest.class / 1.test_case.feature
```

I already tried changing the **runOrder** parameter in pom.xml file, no success.

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
     <runOrder>filesystem</runOrder>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: which all runorder parameter you have checked?

Comment: I tried with "alphabetical", "balanced" and "filesystem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this: eliminating the various **runners**, letting just **one** runner to execute "**.feature**" files.

**The new structure:**

```
src
|- main
|-- java
|--- com.companyname.project
|---- AnotherTestcasePO.java
|---- OtherTestcasePO.java
|---- SomeTestcasePO.java
|--- utils
|---- Project
|- test
|-- java
|--- com.companyname.project
|---- runner
|----- RunYourTest.java
|---- steps
|----- TestcaseSteps.java
testCases
|- 1-SomefeatureFirst.feature
|- 2-OtherfeatureSecond.feature
|- 3-AnotherfeatureThird.feature
```

In my specific project, I changed the test cases folder location to the root of project, but this doesn't affect the execution.

*Reference:* [How to pass multiple parameter to cucumber runner file from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983389/how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-to-cucumber-runner-file-from-jenkins).